# Retrieving JSON throws ClientProtocolException

Tags: android, json, http, exception

I've written two nearly identical methods of retrieving a `JSONObject`. The newer method throws `ClientProtocolException`, code 500. I'm trying to figure out what difference between these two methods could possibly cause one to throw an exception and the other to work perfectly fine.

Method #1:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // fluff

    protected JSONObject retrieveJSON()
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = getString(R.string.url);
        String result = null;
        JSONObject json = null;

        try
        {
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
            ReponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);

            json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Method #2

```
public class ServiceRequest
{
    public ServiceRequest()
    {
    }

    public ServiceRequest(String url)
    {
        this.URL = url;
    }

    public String URL;

    public String execute()
    {
        String result = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(this.URL);

        try
        {
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = httpClient.execute(getRequest, handler);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Both methods return `result` and then process it into a `JSONObject`. Or at least, both methods are supposed to. The only major difference that I can think of is that **Method #1** is coded as a class method of the main activity whereas **Method #2** exists in a stand-alone class. Could this difference be what throws the `ClientProtocolException`?

Comment: Show more of method 2/method 2's class

Comment: and how do you use the class in method 2

Comment: I pass it the url, call it to receive a `String`, and turn that `String` into a `JSONObject`.

Comment: The way you pass the URL is the most likely culprit. You have an invalid getRequest. I'm surprised it's not throwing any exceptions tho. Try logging the URL right before you create the HttpRequest

Comment: @ZedScio The interesting thing is that the URL supplied to both methods is the same. I've checked this at least 5 times and each time, Method #1 works whereas Method #2 doesn't. `getRequest` isn't throwing exceptions but `httpClient.execute` is throwing a ClientProtocolException (Code 500, I think). It's supposedly an Internal Server Error but I can't figure out why such a thing would happen.